# ngf-pattern always failing validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using `ngFileUpload` to upload images to a server upon form submit.

I can upload an image and it appears on the screen without a problem. However, as soon as I hit submit, I get a `pattern` error. When I subsequently remove the image from the input, I can submit the form, and the image actually gets submitted, since it hasn't been deleted in the controller.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-responsive">
<h4>Product Featured Image:</h4>
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="vm.product.featured_image" class="drop-box"
     name="featured_image" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'"
     accept="image/*" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB"
     ngf-change="vm.upload($files, $invalidFiles)">
    <span>Drop</span>
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="vm.product.featured_image">
        <img ngf-src="vm.product.featured_image" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center text-red" ng-show="editForm.featured_image.$error.maxSize">
    Max file size is 2MB. File size: {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB
</div>
```

And my controller method:

```
upload($files, $invalidFiles) {
    if ($files.length > 0) {
        let fileR = new FileReader();
        fileR.onloadend = ((e) => {
            this.product.featured_image = e.target.result;
        });
        fileR.readAsDataURL($files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.product.featured_image = URL.createObjectURL($files[0]);`

Comment: @Endless are you saying I should get rid of the whole `FileReader`?

Comment: yes, i do......

Comment: @Endless Thanks, that worked but now the PHP server side can't open it with `fopen()` (Using `Spatie\MediaLibrary` with Laravel 5.5)

Comment: Also, can you please explain how using `URL` helped?

Comment: Actually, now I see that it didn't help

Comment: You should send the blob/file to the server or append it to a FormData and send that with ajax.